# Turing NP complete but not Karp NP complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions

Is there some examples of candidate problems that have Turing reduction from SAT but no known Karp reduction?

Conversely is there some examples of candidate problems that have Turing reduction to SAT but no known Karp reduction?

Comment: [very related](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/686/6973) ​ ​

Comment: There are duplicates on this site, too, I guess.

Comment: I don't know of any, but see [this paper](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~debasis/papers/fsttcs2014.pdf). ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I think you commented elsewhere that this paper may not be valid.

Answer (score 5):

The complement of any **NP**-complete problem (including SAT itself) is polynomial-time Turing-interreducible with SAT but, there's a Karp reduction if, and only if, **NP$\,=\,$co-NP**.

Comment: what is the explicit reduction?

Comment: Same as the reduction to SAT and then negate the answer.

Comment: Actually what you are saying seems to mean coNP and NP are in P^NP?

Comment: $\mathbf{P}^{\mathbf{NP}}$ is, essentially by definition, exactly the class of problems that are polynomial-time Turing-reducible to SAT so, yes, I am saying that.

Comment: Could there be another example?

Comment: @Student. The language of pairs $(b,f)$ where either $b=1$ and $f$ is a satisfiable formula or $b=0$ and $f$ is an unsatisfiable formula.

Comment: Every co-NP complete problem is not known to have a Karp reduction from SAT and vice versa. So yes we have lot of examples. We will have Karp reduction only in the case if someone is able to prove NP = co-NP.

Comment: I should have said "is there another non-trivial example?" (it is clear unsat is $\mathsf{conp}$ complete).

Comment: @Student. : ​ ​ ​ For any [unary language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_language) L that's not in [P$^{NP(1)}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:P#pnpk), ​ {x : x$\in$SAT [xor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) u[nary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system)(length(x))$\in$L} ​ will be NP-hard under 2-query [truth-table reductions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth-table_reduction) but not under many-one reductions. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer you assume $P\neq P^{NP(1)}$ already.

Comment: Is this easy to see? (the if and only if condition)

Comment: @UserNotFound Yes. If **NP$=$co-NP** then, e.g., UNSAT is in **NP** and reduces to SAT by definition of **NP**-completeness. If UNSAT Karp reduces to SAT then **co-NP$\subseteq$ NP** (you can solve any **co-NP** problem in **NP** by first reducing to UNSAT, then to SAT). The same Karp reduction reduces SAT to UNSAT, so **NP$\subseteq$co-NP**.